# High skew in update query

Tags: teradata

I have a large table - around 2B records. I added a column to the table and am running a simple update query to set the value of my new column to a single value for all rows. The DBA said my query is 90+ skewed and I need to optimize the query.  Anyone have suggestions on how to do that? I am new to working with very large data sets so any advice would be helpful.

Comment: What kind of update: `set newcolumn = value`? If this is a new column why didn't you create it with that value as default? Is the base table skewed?

Comment: Oh, that's a much better way to do it. I just did the update and added the column with the value I wanted as default. Thanks!

Comment: Additionally compress the new value: `ADD newcol ... DEFAULT newvalue COMPRES newvalue`